# Default $resource POST data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

That might be strange but I need to specify some default POST data for my $resource using the factory method of the module.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do that in AngularJS ?

EDIT :

Well, i want to do something like this :

```
/**
 * Module declaration.
 * @type {Object}
 */
var services = angular.module("services", ["ngResource"]);

/**
 * Product handler service
 */
services.factory("Product", function($resource) {
    return $resource("http://someUrl", {}, {
        get   : {method: "GET", params: {productId: "-1"}},
        update: {method : "POST", params:{}, data: {someDataKey: someDataValue}}
    });
});
```

Where data is the default data for my future POST requests.

Comment: What do you send in that data? If you send a token, you should send it in headers, not necessarily in postData...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not really the angular way to do such a thing as you lose data consistency if you do it and it doesn't reflect in your model.

**Why?**

The resource factory creates the object and uses object instance data as POST. I have looked at the documentation and angular-resource.js and there doesn't seem to be a way to specify any default custom properties for the object being created by resource without modifying angular-resource.js.

What you can do is:

```
services.factory("Product", function($resource) {
    return $resource("http://someUrl", {}, {
        get   : {method: "GET", params: {productId: "-1"}},
        update: {method : "POST"}
    });
});
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.product = {}; // your product data initialization stuff
$scope.product.someDataKey = 'someDataValue'; // add your default data

var product = new Product($scope.product);
product.$update();
```

Comment: I suppose we have to stick with that, no default POST values can be set :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it will depend on how you call the update function. If you read the angular main page's tutorial, under "Wire up a Backend", the mongolab.js provides a 'Project' factory. Copied verbatim:

```
angular.module('mongolab', ['ngResource']).
factory('Project', function($resource) {
  var Project = $resource('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases' +
      '/angularjs/collections/projects/:id',
      { apiKey: '4f847ad3e4b08a2eed5f3b54' }, {
        update: { method: 'PUT' }
      }
  );

  Project.prototype.update = function(cb) {
    return Project.update({id: this._id.$oid},
        angular.extend({}, this, {_id:undefined}), cb);
  };

  Project.prototype.destroy = function(cb) {
    return Project.remove({id: this._id.$oid}, cb);
  };

  return Project;
});
```

The usage is that you first get an instance of the Project:

```
project = Project.get({id:1});
```

Then do an update after some changes:

```
project.update(someFunction);
```

In your case, you can change the update to always add the data you need:

```
Product.prototype.update = function(cb) {
  return Product.update({},
      angular.extend({}, this, {someDataKey: someDataValue}), cb);
};
```

Otherwise, you can most likely put the key/value pair in the params:

```
    update: {method : "POST", params:{someDataKey: someDataValue}}
```

It will be POSTed with the key/value pair in the URL, but most app servers nowadays will throw the pair into the params object anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think most have missed a tiny gem in the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

```
non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
```

This suggests you can do the following.

```
var User = $resource('/user');
postData = { name : 'Sunil', 'surname' : 'Shantha' };

var user = User.save({notify:'true'}, postData, function() {
  // success!
});
```

The second parameter when doing a save action (post) is post data.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper function will work.

```
function myPost(data) {
  return $http.post('http://google.com', angular.extend({default: 'value'}, data))
}

myPost().success(function(response) { ... });
```

Comment: It will work indeed, but not the way I pointed out just after your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Might this solve your problem?

```
services.factory("Product", function($resource) {
  return $resource("http://someUrl", {}, {
    get   : {method: "GET", params: {productId: "-1"}},
    update: {method : "POST", params:{}, data: {someDataKey: someDataValue}}
  });
});
services.factory("DefaultProduct", function(Product) {
  return function(){
     return new Product({
        data:"default";
     });
  };
});
services.controller("ProductCTRL",function($scope,DefaultProduct){
  $scope.product = new DefaultProduct();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just [merge](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.extend) your params with the default. Everything **not** available in `params` will be provided by the default object. Everything available will be overwritten by `myParams`

```
services.factory("Product", function($resource) {
    return $resource("http://someUrl", {}, {
        get   : {method: "GET", params: {productId: "-1"}},
        update: {method : "POST", params:angular.extend(myDefault, myParams);}
    });
});
```

where `myParams` would be your list of variables and `myDefault` your default values as a json object.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default fields on your request by using *transformRequest* option for your *$resource*'s actions that use the *POST* method.

For example something like this

```
function prependTransform(defaults, transform) {

 // We can't guarantee that the default transformation is an array
 defaults = angular.isArray(defaults) ? defaults : [defaults];

 // Append the new transformation to the defaults
 return [transform].concat(defaults);
}

ctrl.factory('MyResource', ['$resource', '$http',
function($resource, $http) {
    return $resource('/path/to/myresource/:id', {id : '@id'},
           { 
               create : {
                   method : 'POST',
                   transformRequest : prependTransform($http.defaults.transformRequest,
                      function(data, headers) {
                           return addDefaultField(data);
                      }
                  ),
               },
           });
    }
]);
```